# Radio Button Click from another page

Tags: html, css, radio-button, checked

I have two page. First page have a menu. Radio buttons in other page.

Radio button will be selected on the other page when i click in first page.

For example, first page:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Other page:

```
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" checked id="tab1" class="tab-content-1">
                <label for="tab1"><span><span>1</span></span></label>

                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" class="tab-content-2">
                <label for="tab2"><span><span>2</span></span></label>

                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" class="tab-content-3">
                <label for="tab3"><span><span>3</span></span></label>

                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" class="tab-content-4">
                <label for="tab4"><span><span>4</span></span></label>

                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" class="tab-content-5">
                <label for="tab5"><span><span>5</span></span></label>

                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab6" class="tab-content-6">
                <label for="tab6"><span><span>6</span></span></label>
```

I want to click 1 in menu on first page, go to checked radio button other page. So i need radio buton link. If i have radio button link, it take href.

```
<a href="checked link????">1</a>  ---> go to checked 1 other page.
```

Answer (score 0):

To check a radio button, you should use javascript instead of url. Considering that the action is cross-page, you might call the url with an extra parameter.

URL in the first page: `<link_to_the_second_page>?check=1`

And in the second page, get the URL parameter via javascript (you might use regex to extract the value in `window.location.search`), and then check the related radio button.